# get all the account where account owner = current login user

Tags: apex, lightning, soql, community

```
List<Account> accName =  [Select Id,Name from Account where Account_Owner__c = : UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

i just want  to get all the account where account owner = current login user

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ? Are you populating `Account_Owner__c` field with the `Owner` of Account ?

Answer (score 1):

To get account owner you need to use OwnerId field, see below code snippet.

```
List<Account> accName =  [Select Id,Name from Account where OwnerId = : UserInfo.getUserId()];
```